# How can I implement notification system with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a notification zone that I want to be updated when someone sends a message for example using jQuery or Ajax (my database is in a soap server) I want to do the soap call every second or so, how can I do that?

Comment: `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`? As far as I know, the only way to have more than one thread in JS is with web-workers, but you don't need that for this requirement.

Comment: what does this have to do with threads?

Comment: @user One cannot make mistakes?

Comment: @SeekingKnowledge Anyone can make mistakes. But don't take it personally when you're notified that you just made one.

Comment: @bažmegakapa :Fair enough :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a simple `setInterval` structure to execute AJAX calls at predefined intervals. Something like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.get('ajax_responder.php',dataObj,function(){
    // ajax callback
    // here is where you would update the user with any new notifications.
  });
},5000);
```

The previous code will execute an AJAX request every 5000 miliseconds (every 5 seconds).

References:

- [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)
- [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

Comment: Even though it would be wiser to use chained `setTimeout`s so they surely will not pile up.

Comment: @baz - **very true**. I haven't got much time to expand on that - you are very welcome to made some edits to my answer outlining that issue.

Comment: And there is a thing new, right now called WebWorkers which you can see how they work : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `setInterval()`, I would **strongly** suggest to use `setTimeout()`.

[MDN explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setInterval#Dangerous_usage):

> If there is a possibility that your logic could take longer to execute
>   than the interval time, it is recommended that you recursively call a
>   named function using `window.setTimeout`. For example, if using
>   setInterval to poll a remote server every 5 seconds, network latency,
>   an unresponsive server, and a host of other issues could prevent the
>   request from completing in its alloted time. As such, you may find
>   yourself with queued up XHR requests that won't necessarily return in
>   order.
>
> For such cases, a recursive `setTimeout` pattern is preferred:
>
> ```
> (function loop(){    
>     setTimeout(function(){
>
>         // logic here
>
>         // recurse
>         loop();
>     }, 1000); 
> })();
> ```
>
> In the above snippet, a named function loop is declared and is immediately executed. 
>   `loop` is recursively called
>   inside `setTimeout` after the logic has completed executing. While this
>   pattern does not guarantee execution on a fixed interval, it does
>   guarantee that the previous interval has completed before recursing.

Answer (score 1):

The best way for real-time web is [**node.js**](http://nodejs.org/).

> Node.js is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime for easily building fast, scalable network applications. Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and efficient, perfect for data-intensive real-time applications that run across distributed devices.

But you can do it by [**setInterval or setTimeout**](http://w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp), put an [**Ajax**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/) call in your interval.

```
var intval = setInterval( function() 
{
   $.get('url.php',  {data1: "value1", data2: "value2"},  
   function(response)
   {  
            // response  
   });  
}, 1000);
```